# Python need to find the input table name from the file name

Tags: python, filenames

I have a file ABC_costing and I need the ABC from the file so I can tell the script to put the data into  the table PROD."ABCproduction".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my_name = "ABC_costing"
prefix = my_name.split("_")[0]
new_name = "{}production".format(prefix)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I receive excel files that come in with all different file names but the first 3 charters will always tell me the production table I need to send the data. For example the file could be ABC_1234 or DEF_3344 or EFG_4456.                                I need then the imput table to be PROD."ABCproduction". or PROD."DEFproduction" or PROD.EFGproduction"       Thanks for more help